# Programming in C - Problem

Tags: c

Following is the C Code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int a,b,d;
void Values1()
{
    a=a*2;
    b=b-5;
}

void Values2(register int c)
{
    d+=b-c;
    a=a+10;
    b*=3;
}
int a,b;

int main()
{
    int i=7;
    Values2(i);
    Values1();
    printf("a=%d, b=%d, d=%d\n",a,b,d);
    system("pause");
}
```

It Gives a Compilation Error related to redefinition of 'a' and 'b' in MS Visual C++ 2010.
Please help me in figuring out why this error has occured.

Comment: It is valid as C, but invalid as C++. How are you compiling this?

Answer (score 4):

You define a and b in the global scope here:

```
int a,b,d;
```

and here

```
int a,b;
```

You can not define variables twice.

Comment: Wrong: they are "tentative definitions".

Comment: If you compile with Visual C++ it might get compiled as C++, which doesn't have tentative definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have these *two* lines?

```
int a,b,d;
int a,b;
```

You only need to define the variables *once.* I'd suggest getting rid of the second line.

---

Some other things you *may* want to consider in the interests of furthering your skills.

- Global variables are usually consider a bad thing. There are better ways to do it which encapsulate information much better, and will reduce the likelihood of problems down the track.
- Use meaningful variable names. They only slow down the compiler the tiniest bit and will not affect your running speed, but they make your code so much easier to maintain.
- I like to space out expressions to make them more readable as well, like `d += b - c;` instead of `d+=b-c;`.
- Don't bother with the `register` keyword, it's a *suggestion* to the compiler and most modern compilers are far better than developers at figuring out how best to optimise code.
- There are two canonical prototypes for main and `int main()` isn't one of them - use `int main (void)` if you don't care about program arguments.
- On pre-C99 compilers, you should return 0 from `main` (C99 will return 0 for you if you reach the closing brace of `main`).

Comment: "There are two canonical prototypes for `main` and `int main()` isn't one of them - use `int main (void)` if you don't care about program arguments." I was under the impression that `foo(void)` and `foo()` could be used interchangeably in function definitions.

Comment: @sepp2k: no, `foo()` is a prototype about which no argument information is given, `foo(void)` is a prototype where the information is given that exactly zero arguments are required. It's one of the subtle corners of the standard :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yes, that's true when you declare a function. But, as far as I am aware, `()` is completely equivalent to `(void)` in a function *definition*, so it's perfectly valid to declare a function as `(void)` and then define it using `()` and by extension it should be perfectly valid to define main as `int main()`. At least that's how I've always understood it.

Comment: @sepp2k: C99 states that only `int main(void) { /* ... */ }` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }` (or equivalent such as with `char **argv`) are blessed. Others are _possible_ but that's an implementation-defined thing, not part of the requirements of the standard.

Comment: @sepp2k: I think `foo(void)` and `foo()` are equivalent prototypes in C++. They are different in C.

Comment: @pax: C99 already introduced the implicit `return 0;` before the closing brace of the `main` function :)

Comment: @pmg: I did not know that. Thanks for the info, updated answer to better reflect reality :-)

Comment: Multiple **declarations** of variables are allowed (though bad form): they are "tentative definitions".

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is badly configured. **Your program is legal C**.

The re-declarations of `a` and `b` fall into the category of `"tentative definition"`. A properly configured C compiler, cannot stop compilation because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Right after the definition of `Values2()`, there is the line `int a,b;` which will conflict with `int a,b,d;` before `Values1()`, so you can safely remove the line `int a,b;`.

Besides, to get good results, you may want to set tha values of `a`, `b` and `c` in the start of the main function to get consistent results.